# Blurred phone wallpaper as background of activity?

Tags: android, screenshot, blur, wallpaper

I have manged to set the current wallpaper as the background of the Activity:

```
Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

**I want to blur this background, but for that I have to save it as a Bitmap first. Is there a way to do this?**

If I try to take a screenshot with this code, it just captures the views of my Activity, but **not** its background:

```
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

//This bitmap should be the wallpaper:
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache()); 

v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

I know, I can use `WallpaperManager` to get the whole Wallpaper as a Drawable, but...

- I just want to get the visible part of it (if it's a scrolling wallpaper I don't want to get the parts that are out of the screen)
- it gives me the last static wallpaper if the current one is a live wallpaper

Maybe you can help me ;)

Comment: Hi, were you able to achieve this? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: No, I wasn't. There seems to be no way of either getting the actual background bitmap nor manipulating/blurring the background part 'behind' the app :/